# Associar valores de um input ao plano mais proximo com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um input range que vai de `0 a 400.000` cada step de `5.000` e tenho um conjunto de planos `(50.000, 70.000, 100.000, 120.000, 150.000, 200.000, 220.000, 250.000, 300.000, 350.000, 380.000 e 400.000 )` cada plano desse contem informações diferentes que serão colocados dentro de uma table.

Bom preciso vincular os valores colocado no input range pelo usuário ao plano mais próximo, ex: valor do range = 20.000 será vinculado ao plano 50.000.

**Após esse processo o valor sera inserido em (valores.vcredito):**

`makeTable(valores.vcredito, json.planos, document.querySelector('tbody'));`

Os únicos valores que vão funcionar no lugar de `valores.vcredito` são os dos planos, por isso preciso transformar o valor do input range no valor do plano mais proximo.

Não sei se ficou muito claro mas qualquer coisa tento melhorar a pergunta.

Obrigado.

**Editado**:

Tenho o seguinte código que monta uma tabela de acordo com o plano escolhido:

```js
const json = {
    "planos": [{
     "nome": "Imóvel 50",
     "credito": "50000",
     "100 parcelas": "R$605,00",
     "120 parcelas": "R$512,50",
     "135 parcelas": "R$462,96",
     "150 parcelas": "R$423,33 ",
     "180 parcelas": "-"
    }, {
     "nome": "Imóvel 70",
     "credito": "70000",
     "100 parcelas": "R$847,00",
     "120 parcelas": "R$717,50 ",
     "135 parcelas": "R$648,15",
     "150 parcelas": "R$592,67",
     "180 parcelas": "R$493,89"
    }, {
     "nome": "Imóvel 100",
     "credito": "100000",
     "100 parcelas": "R$1.210,00",
     "120 parcelas": "R$1.025,00",
     "135 parcelas": "R$925,93",
     "150 parcelas": "R$846,67",
     "180 parcelas": "R$705,56"
    }, {
     "nome": "Imóvel 120",
     "credito": "120000",
     "100 parcelas": "R$1.452,00",
     "120 parcelas": "R$1.230,00",
     "135 parcelas": "R$1.111,11",
     "150 parcelas": "R$1.016,00",
     "180 parcelas": "R$846,67"
    }, {
     "nome": "Imóvel 150",
     "credito": "150000",
     "100 parcelas": "R$1.452,00",
     "120 parcelas": "R$1.230,00",
     "135 parcelas": "R$1.111,11",
     "150 parcelas": "R$1.016,00",
     "180 parcelas": "R$846,67"
    }, {
     "nome": "Imóvel 200",
     "credito": "200000",
     "100 parcelas": "R$2.420,00 ",
     "120 parcelas": "R$2.050,00 ",
     "135 parcelas": "R$1.851,85 ",
     "150 parcelas": "R$1.693,33",
     "180 parcelas": "R$1.411,11 "
    }, {
     "nome": "Imóvel 220",
     "credito": "220000",
     "100 parcelas": "R$2.662,00",
     "120 parcelas": "R$2.255,00",
     "135 parcelas": "R$2.037,04",
     "150 parcelas": "R$1.862,67",
     "180 parcelas": "R$1.552,22"
    }, {
     "nome": "Imóvel 250",
     "credito": "250000",
     "100 parcelas": "R$3.025,00",
     "120 parcelas": "R$2.562,50",
     "135 parcelas": "R$2.314,81",
     "150 parcelas": "R$2.116,67",
     "180 parcelas": "R$1.763,89"
    }, {
     "nome": "Imóvel 300",
     "credito": "300000",
     "100 parcelas": "R$3.630,00",
     "120 parcelas": "R$3.075,00",
     "135 parcelas": "R$2.777,78",
     "150 parcelas": "R$2.540,00",
     "180 parcelas": "R$2.116,67"
    }, {
     "nome": "Imóvel 350",
     "credito": "350000",
     "100 parcelas": "R$4.235,00 ",
     "120 parcelas": "R$3.587,50",
     "135 parcelas": "R$3.240,74",
     "150 parcelas": "R$2.963,33",
     "180 parcelas": "R$2.469,44"
    }, {
     "nome": "Imóvel 380",
     "credito": "380000",
     "100 parcelas": "R$4.598,00",
     "120 parcelas": "R$3.895,00",
     "135 parcelas": "R$3.518,52",
     "150 parcelas": "R$3.217,33",
     "180 parcelas": "R$2.681,11"
    }, {
     "nome": "Imóvel 400",
     "credito": "400000",
     "100 parcelas": "R$4.840,00",
     "120 parcelas": "R$4.100,00",
     "135 parcelas": "R$3.703,70",
     "150 parcelas": "R$3.386,67",
     "180 parcelas": "R$2.822,22"
    }]
   };

   var valorCredito = $('#valores-credito').val();
   var valorParcela = $('#valores-parcela').val();

   function makeTable(credito, arr, target) {
    target.innerHTML = '';
    var data = arr.filter(imo => imo.credito == credito)[0];
    if (!data) return;
    Object.keys(data).filter(k => k.match(/\d+\s\parcelas/)).forEach(k => {
     var tr = document.createElement('tr');
     [k, '<span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-info-circle"></span>Mais informações', data[k]].forEach(content => {
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      td.innerHTML = content;
      tr.appendChild(td);
     });
     target.appendChild(tr);
    });
   }

   makeTable(valores.vcredito, json.planos, document.querySelector('tbody'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta você varrer a lista item a item e logo que "passar", o valor válido é o último.
Pelo que você citou no exemplo, o input range é um valor só. (Mas input range dá a entender que será uma faixa)

Como você não postou nenhum trecho de código, vou dar um exemplo para buscar o valor mínimo:

```
bool passou = false;
int indice = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < valores.size(); i++) {
  if (valorSendoTestado >= valores[i]) {
    passou = true;
    indice = i;
    break;
  }
}
// aqui a variável indice terá o valor do índice do array "valores"
// cujo valor está logo abaixo do "valorSendoTestado"
```

- não está otimizado, eu quis escrever de forma bem expandida para facilitar o entendimento

Se a input range for composta de dois valores (mínimo e máximo), pode-se executar o laço comparando com o valor superior da escala.

Espero ter ajudado/respondido!

Comment: na verdade o input so tem um valor e é aquele input slider,  o amigo la em cima colocou um exemplo e funcionou, porem tentei colocar no meu código mas acabou dando erro na variavel sugestao como indefinida.  Que parte de código posso postar para ficar mais facil do pessoal entender?

Comment: Pelo código que você postou, consegui fazer alguns testes e tive bons resultados.
Na linha que faz o `filter`, basta filtrar pelos elementos cujo crédito seja menor que o passado como parâmetro e pegar o último elemento. Resumindo:
`var data = arr.filter(imo => imo.credito <= credito).pop();`

Pelo seu código não dá para saber de onde vem o `valores.vcredito`, mas garantindo que ali está um valor numérico, o restante vai funcionar.

Comment: Coloquei no JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/cuwbnsb2/1/)

Comment: `valores.vcredito`  vem do valor colocado pelo usuario no input range , vou dar uma olhada no codigo que vc fez e ver se consigo colocar aqui, mto obrigado

Comment: O código deu certo porem quando coloco um valor na `var valores` abaixo de 50000 ele não arredonda para 50000.

Comment: Mudei um pouco para pegar esse caso também: (https://jsfiddle.net/osmarcf/cuwbnsb2/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa encontrar o valor dentro do array que se aproxima ao informado no slider, você pode fazer isto usando o `reduce`.

```js
var planos = [50000, 70000, 100000, 120000, 150000, 200000, 220000, 250000, 300000, 350000, 380000, 400000];

var proposto = document.getElementById("proposto");
var plano = document.getElementById("plano");

proposto.addEventListener("input", function (event) {
  var valor = proposto.valueAsNumber;  
  var sugestao = planos.reduce(function (atual, plano) {
    var diffAtual = Math.abs(valor - atual);
    var diffPlano = Math.abs(valor - plano);
    return diffAtual < diffPlano ? atual : plano;
  });
  plano.value = sugestao;
})
```

```html
<label>
  Valor Proposto:
  <input id="proposto" type="number" min="0" max="400000" step="5000" />
</label>

<label>
  Valor Plano:
  <input id="plano" type="text" value="" readonly />
</label>
```

**P.S.** Enquanto eu estava montando a resposta, sugiram as demais.

Comment: legal mais ou menos igual seu exemplo mesmo, vou dar uma olhada e ver como posso adaptar ao meu código, qualquer coisa aviso aqui, Obrigado.

Comment: não estou conseguindo colocar no meu codigo, quando dou um console.log (sugestao) fala que sugestao esta indefinido.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você quer arredondar um valor arbitrário para algum que esteja em uma lista de valores válidos. Certamente há uma forma mais eficiente, dado que sua lista está ordenada, mas um método intuitivo seria percorrer toda a lista procurando a diferença mínima entre o valor dado e cada elemento da lista.

```
arredondar = function(lista,valor){
    var minDif = Infinity;
    var minIndice = 0;
    var dif = 0;
    for(i in lista){
        dif = Math.abs(lista[i] - valor);
        if (dif < minDif){
            minDif = dif;
            minIndice = i;
        }
    }
    return lista[minIndice];
}
```

Acho que com essa ideia inicial você consegue adaptar para seu caso.